# How to add a marker to the middle of a polygon in leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I want to add a marker in the middle of a polygon that is made form geojson data. The polygon is connected a control where the layer can be turned on and off. This marker should only be displayed when the layer is active. I have the following code:

```
var geoJsonLayer = L.geoJSON(Locations, {
  onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
    if (feature.geometry.type === "Polygon") {
      var bounds = layer.getBounds();
      var center = bounds.getCenter();

      var markerTitle = feature.properties.ItemId;
      layer.id = markerTitle;

      var popUpFormat = dataPopUp(feature);
      layer.bindPopup(popUpFormat, customPopUpOptions);
    }
  },
});
```

Thanks for your interest and I hope someone can help me :D

Comment: `var marker = L.marker(center).addTo(mymap);`

Comment: Thanks for your response! I am trying to connect the marker with the rest of the layer. The layer can be active or not active. When I try this function the marker is always active, even when the layer is deactivated.

Answer (score 1):

You want to group a `L.Polygon` and a `L.Marker` together, and treat them as the same entity. This is a textbook scenario for using `L.LayerGroup`s, e.g.

```
var geoJsonLayer = L.geoJSON(Locations, {
  onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
    if (feature.geometry.type === "Polygon") {
      var center = layer.getBounds().getCenter();
      var marker = L.marker(center);
      var polygonAndItsCenter = L.layerGroup([layer, marker]);
    }
  },
});
```

Now `polygonAndItsCenter` is a `L.LayerGroup` with the polygon and its center (so adding/removing to/from the map will apply to both), but `geoJsonLayer` will contain only the polygons. How you handle that is up to you, but I guess you might want to *not* add `geoJson` to the map (using only for parsing and instantiating the polygons), and keep track of your polygon+marker `LayerGroup`s separately, e.g.

```
var polygonsWithCenters = L.layerGroup();

var geoJsonLayer = L.geoJSON(Locations, {
  onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
    if (feature.geometry.type === "Polygon") {
      var center = layer.getBounds().getCenter();
      var marker = L.marker(center);
      var polygonAndItsCenter = L.layerGroup([layer, marker]);
      polygonAndItsCenter.addTo(polygonsWithCenters);
    }
  },
});

// geoJsonLayer.addTo(map);  // No!!
polygonsWithCenters.addTo(map);

// Do something with a polygon+marker, e.g. remove the first one from the map
polygonsWithCenters.getLayers()[0].remove();
```

There are a few secondary problems that can spawn for this, so think about what you want to do with each polygon/layergroup/marker before writing code, keep the Leaflet documentation at hand, and remember:

- You can not attach events or bind popups to `LayerGroup`s, but you can do that to `L.FeatureGroup`s
- The center of a polygon's bounding box is different from its [centroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid) which is different from the [point inside the polygon which is furthest away from any of its edges](https://github.com/mapbox/polylabel). Only the third option is guaranteed to be *inside* the polygon.